# $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST not being populated

Tags: php, post, get

I inherited an XP machine with xitami/pro server running on it and installed PHP 5.2.17 because I thought I might need the VC6 version.

PHP works and the `phpinfo` shows as it should.  When I do `www.domain.com/test.php?x=y&z=test` the `$_GET` is not being populated.

The `$_REQUEST` variable is not being populated either.  If I post it in a form and post it, the `$_POST` is empty as is the `$_REQUEST`.

If I loop through the `$_SERVER` variables and display them on a get, the `QUERY_STRING` is populated with the get variables.

When I do a `print_r` on any of the variables, it is empty.  I get: `Array ( ) 1`

I then upgraded to PHP 5.4 and the same thing.

What is the problem?  I am at a loss and don't know what else to try.

Comment: Probably some htaccess redirect?

Comment: How is PHP deployed? Which server (apache, nginx, iis, etc), what protocol (fcgi, mod_php, etc)?

Comment: The server is Xitami/pro.  Is is deployed as cgi.  I added a filter to the xitami cfg so that .php executes php.exe.  I am certainly not a configuration expert and have never worked with xitami before.

Comment: Have a look at [`variables_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect this problem arises when the server is configured wrong. Especially when the wrong SAPI is used (for example, I'm pretty sure `$_GET`/`$_POST` are not available when using the [PHP CLI](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php).

To see if this causes your issue, create a new php file, and insert the following

```
<?php
  echo php_sapi_name();
?>
```

In case this returns `CLI` I'm pretty sure that causes your issues. Solve it by configuring your server to use the correct SAPI.

TL;DR:
I assume you're using `C:\php\php.exe` as your PHP interpreter. Try `C:\php\php-cgi.exe` instead.

Comment: It returned cli as you said.  Any suggestion on what I need to change?

Comment: I tried php-cgi.exe and with 5.2 it said access denied.  With 5.4 I got a page that said: Security Alert! The PHP CGI cannot be accessed directly.
This PHP CGI binary was compiled with force-cgi-redirect enabled. This means that a page will only be served up if the REDIRECT_STATUS CGI variable is set, e.g. via an Apache Action directive.  Not sure what to try.

Comment: I also tried php-win.exe.  This seems to work the same as php.exe.

Comment: I found a comment that said to set  cgi.force_redirect to 0.  I did that and now am getting access denied in 5.4 as well.

Comment: Have you installed PHP as explained on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.xitami.php)?

Comment: setting `cgi.force_redirect = 0` in your php.ini file seems to necessary for Xitami.

Comment: the 5.2 install had it already set, that is why i was getting access denied.  How can I troubleshoot the access denied issue?

Comment: I changed the permissions on the php-cgi.exe file to full control for all and it still is giving me that issue.  I even tried setting the whole php directory to full control, but that did not do it either.  I am still getting access denied.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25178/discussion-between-genesys-and-user999684)